# filter with string return nothing

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I run into follow problem. Did I miss anything?

```
Association.all().count()
1

Association.all().fetch(1)
[Association(**{'server_url': u'server-url', 'handle': u'handle2', 'secret': 'c2VjcmV0\n', 'issued': 1242892477L, 'lifetime': 200L, 'assoc_type': u'HMAC-SHA1'})]

Association.all().filter('server_url =', 'server-url').count()
0  # expect 1

Association.all().filter('server_url =', u'server-url').count()
0 # expect 1

Association.all().filter('issued >', 0).count()
1
```

Comment: Don't know GAE, but should the "=" be "==" instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of property is "server_url"?

If it is a TextProperty, then it cannot be used in filters.

> Unlike StringProperty, a TextProperty
>   value can be more than 500 bytes long.
>   However, TextProperty values are not
>   indexed, and cannot be used in filters
>   or sort orders.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#TextProperty

Comment: User posted the same thing on the official forums; this was the solution.